# Using Mono to complete Universal Windows Platform (.net core)

Tags: mono, itext, win-universal-app, .net-core

We are using some old open-source .Net Framework libraries that depend on things that are not in .Net Core.  Can Mono be used to fill in the rest of .Net Framework?

Specifically I'm thinking of creating a Universal Windows class library that includes everything in Mono (excluding some of the System namespace) that changes the namespaces from System.* to MonoSupport.System.*.

Of course, better approaches would be to re-write the library's code, use a different library, or be more selective in taking things from Mono.  I was hoping to do this as a temporary measure.

(I want to use iTextSharpLGPL but it uses XmlTextReader, streams with .Close(), System.Security.Cryptography, etc..  The pay version of the library [does not support UWP either](http://itextpdf.com/blog/itextsharp-and-uwp).)

**Edit**: I gave up on this and rewrote my app to use Apitron.  That worked great until I tried to deploy and found out they don't support .NET Native.  I'm now waiting for some library to support PDF generation on UWP.

Comment: I know, but we're working on it.

Comment: The upcoming iText 7 for .NET is expected to be compatible with UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think so. The following immediate reasons

- Mono is a clone of the .NET Framework and therefore based on mscorlib ideas, while UWP is based on System.Runtime. Would require significant extra effort.
- UWP apps - when released - are based on the .NET Native runtime. This runtime enforces some patterns in the library implementations (e.g. no reflection, no C++ implementation of types etc). Mono is also strong in AOT, but I think there are dragons.
- Mono is a bad choice. Better is the microsoft referencesource for the .NET Framework as published on github.

The time you will invest in your plan will be so significant high, it is much better invested fixing it in corefx directly and wait for the next release of UWP to contain your fixes.

For your problem I would urgently recommend you to fix the problem as a submission upstream at iTextSharpLGPL by surfacing new methods and removing of close or maybe by just copying the MIT licensed XmlTtextReader. But I highly recommend you, not to mess around with crypto ;)